Manhattan Distance Minimum Spanning Tree
I'm working on a Steiner Tree algorithm for rectilinear graphs (Manhattan distance) and first of all I need to compute a minimum spanning tree as an upper bound, also with Manhattan distance. This is where I'm a bit lost.
I know about the standard algorithms for MST, like Prim or Kruskal, but I'm having trouble coming up with something for rectilinear MST. I'm also not quite sure how this MST is any different to the actual Steiner Tree. I know that a Steiner Tree can use extra nodes but isn't a rectilinear MST also using extra nodes? If you look at this example, it looks to me like in the MST, there are two extra nodes and in the Steiner Tree there's one.
MST vs Steiner Tree
I'd be very happy about some help regarding my understanding of the problem and also my search for an algorithm.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the About page soon and also visit the links describing How to Ask a Question and How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

@DavidC.Rankin The question seems to satisfy every point in [ask] and the first line in [mre] says “ When asking a debugging question…”, which doesn’t seem to apply here. I’m not sure what else the OP needs to improve.

@beaker Ask yourself this "What is the specific question?" and "which part of what paragraph is the actual question in?" It can't just be "I know that a Steiner Tree can use extra nodes but isn't a rectilinear MST also using extra nodes?" This question does indeed need more focus.

@DavidC.Rankin It seems to me that the question is "what is the algorithm for constructing a rectilinear MST".

Seems lacking in What topics can I ask about here? (no. 3 last sentence)

@DavidC.Rankin Seems to be an exact fit for the 2nd bullet at the top, "a software algorithm..."

@grünewuzz17 Now that I'm back from vacation and have access to my computer, my understanding is that the edges of a rectilinear minimum spanning tree are not constrained to vertical/horizontal with bends when drawing the tree, but are still connected directly between vertices, just like you would when using the Euclidean distance. The Manhattan distance is only used to determine which vertices should be connected. See wikipedia for an example.
